# Dividing two longs resulting in unexpected results

Tags: java, combinations, long-integer, division

I am writing code that calculates combinations (e.g. 7 choose 3 = 25), for a kata on code wars(https://www.codewars.com/kata/color-choice/train/java), the task is to find the lowest value of x in this formula:

```
m = n choose x
```

which equates to:

```
m = n! / (x! * (n - x)!)
```

given n and m. My code is working well for numbers within the int range (although all variables are declared as longs), although when the numbers get bigger the division process results in incorrect values.

I have tried looking elsewhere for answers as to why the division with large longs results this way, but the only solutions are for instances where the user is defining the long by a number, to which they add an L to the suffix of the value, whereas in my code, there is no direct hard-coding of any values. Can anyone shed any light on why i could getting results such as these for my calculations

Code:

```
public class Checkchoose {

public static long checkchoose(long m, int n) {
  long facN = factorial((long)n);
  long calc=0, x=0;
  while(calc!=m && x<=n){
    x++;
    System.out.println("n="+n+" x="+x);
    long facX=factorial(x);
    long nx = factorial(n-x);
    calc=facN/(facX*nx);
    System.out.println("facN="+facN+" facX="+facX+" calc="+calc);
  }
  System.out.println("n="+n+" x="+x+"\n");
  if(x>n) return -1;
  else    return x;
}
public static long factorial(long val){
  long out=1;
  for(long i=val; i>0; i--) out*=i;
  return out;
  }
}
```

Code working:

```
m = 184756
n=20 x=1
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=1 calc=20
n=20 x=2
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=2 calc=190
n=20 x=3
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=6 calc=1140
n=20 x=4
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=24 calc=4845
n=20 x=5    
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=120 calc=15504
n=20 x=6
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=720 calc=38760
n=20 x=7
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=5040 calc=77520
n=20 x=8
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=40320 calc=125970
n=20 x=9
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=362880 calc=167960
n=20 x=10
facN=2432902008176640000 facX=3628800 calc=184756
20 choose 10 = 184756
```

Code Not Working:

```
    m = 3268760
    n=25 x=1
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=1 calc=0
    n=25 x=2
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=2 calc=-3
    n=25 x=3
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=6 calc=0
    n=25 x=4
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=24 calc=0
    n=25 x=5
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=120 calc=-2
    n=25 x=6
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=720 calc=-1
    n=25 x=7
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=5040 calc=-1
    n=25 x=8
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=40320 calc=-1
    n=25 x=9
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=362880 calc=0
    n=25 x=10
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=3628800 calc=1
    n=25 x=11
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=39916800 calc=2
    n=25 x=12
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=479001600 calc=2
    n=25 x=13
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=6227020800 calc=2
    n=25 x=14
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=87178291200 calc=2
    n=25 x=15
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=1307674368000 calc=1
    n=25 x=16
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=20922789888000 calc=0
    n=25 x=17
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=355687428096000 calc=-1
    n=25 x=18
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=6402373705728000 calc=-1
    n=25 x=19
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=121645100408832000 calc=-1
    n=25 x=20
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=2432902008176640000 calc=-2
    n=25 x=21
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=-4249290049419214848 calc=0
    n=25 x=22
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=-1250660718674968576 calc=0
    n=25 x=23
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=8128291617894825984 calc=-3
    n=25 x=24
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=-7835185981329244160 calc=0
    n=25 x=25
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=7034535277573963776 calc=1
    n=25 x=26
    facN=7034535277573963776 facX=-1569523520172457984 calc=-4
    n=25 x=26

Expected: <10> but was <-1> 
25 choose 10 = 3268760
```

Comment: Obviously the factorial is overflowing and going negative.

Comment: consider using `BigInteger`

Comment: I assumed when storing the result of a long division in a long variable that it would deter overflow, no?

Comment: also, I tried using big integer but the problem still persists, with the large numbers the division results in overflow